# local by flywheel is not showing agree button

Tags: wordpress, local

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJWug.png)I am installing local by flywheel but at the first page it shows agree button for terms and conditions but that button is not active, so how can I proceed? please tell

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to check you agree to the terms of service before agree becomes active